# Wrong bitshift results

Tags: c#, bit-shift

I'm working with bitshift for the first time and I'm experiencing unexpected results.

I'm declaring the shift amount as follows:

```
byte p_size = 0;
if (ver == 0x12 || ver == 0x13)
    p_size = 20;
else
    p_size = 40;
```

The value to be shifted is declared as

```
int t_size = rinput.ReadInt32();
```

And finally the code I use to shift:

```
int temp = t_size >> p_size << p_size;
```

---

Let's say t_size = 0x2000385E and p_size = 20. temp = 0x20000000 as expected.

Now if t_size = 0x40001014 and p_size = 40, temp = 0x40001000 instead of 0x40000000. I calculated "manually" using a bitwise calculator and it matches the expected result of 0x40000000.

It's probably a silly oversight on my behalf but I don't understand what would cause the weird results with p_size = 40... any advice is appreciated!

Comment: What do you *expect* from shifting 32 bits to the left by 40 positions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Shifting a 32 integer by 40 bits doesn't really make sense since you would be shifting the integer by more bits than it contains.

Both the [left](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a1sway8w.aspx) and [right](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xt18et0d.aspx) shift operators document what they do in this case:

> If the first operand is an int or uint (32-bit quantity), the shift
>   count is given by the low-order five bits of the second operand
>   (second operand & 0x1f).

So when `p_size` is 40, the shifts are shifting by `40 & 0x1f = 8 bits.`

If you need to shift by 40 bits, but your value into  `long`.

Answer (score 5):

Current behavior is expected as 40 & 0x1f is 8 as described in [operator >>](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xt18et0d.aspx)

> If the first operand is an int or uint (32-bit quantity), the shift count is given by the low-order five bits of the second operand (second operand & 0x1f).

You probably looking for some masking rather than shifts - maybe

```
  t_size & 0xFF000000
```